# If I delete system 32 can I get it back from the recycle bin?

Tags: file, window, windows-10, system32

This may be a stupid question, but I was wondering if the system 32 file is deleted from its original place can I get it back from the recycle bin?

Comment: If you do that your computer will be to messed up in the first place to even open the recycle bin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not be able to delete system32 while the OS is running.  Unlike with Linux, files in use will prevent deleting it.  However, unused files will be deleted.  If you use the Windows file explorer, files will go to the Recycle Bin.  If you delete from command line, they will not.